# Obtaining the phonon Hamiltonian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, phonons

I am currently following Ashcroft's Solid State Physics. In Appendix L, he proceeds to show how to derive the phonon Hamiltonian

$$
H=\sum\hbar\omega_s(k)(a_{ks}^{\dagger}a_{ks}+1/2)
$$

where

$$
a_{ks}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_Re^{-ikR}\epsilon_s(k)\left[\sqrt{\frac{M\omega_s(k)}{2\hbar}}u(R)+i\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\hbar M\omega_s(k)}}P(R)\right]
$$

and similarly for $a_{ks}^{\dagger}$.

I am able to obtain the correct expressions for $u(R)$ and $P(R)$ without much struggle. However, when I calculate the hamiltonian I reach to

$H=1/2\sum\hbar\omega_s(k)(a_{-ks}a_{-ks}^{\dagger}+a_{ks}^{\dagger}a_{ks})$

instead of

$H=1/2\sum\hbar\omega_s(k)(a_{ks}a_{ks}^{\dagger}+a_{ks}^{\dagger}a_{ks})$

which does indeed easily lead you to the desired expression.

I have tried to go from my expression to the simplified hamiltonian and the problem is reduced to the demonstration that

$[P_s^*(k)Q_s(k)-Q_s^*(k)P_s(k)]=i\hbar$

(I denote as Q the generalized coordinates)

This is true if $P_s^*(k)=P_s(k)$ and similarly for Q, but I was given the condition that $P_s^*(k)=P_s(-k)$ in the subject's lectures and I cannot go past that point; I always reach a result that requires the former.

As far as I understand,
   $a_{-ks}a_{-ks}^{\dagger}=a_{ks}a_{ks}^{\dagger}$ also implies that $P_s^*(k)=P_s(k)$.

My question is:

- How is this $P_s^*(k)=P_s(-k)$ condition physically justified and in
  which case can I (if I can at all) assume that $P_s^*(k)=P_s(k)$? The condition was given to us without any further justification and I have been unable to see it in any of the books I have checked (i.e. Ashcroft, Marder, Ibach and Kittel).

**EDIT:**

I have realized that $a_{-ks}a_{-ks}^{\dagger}$ is in fact inside a sum over k so having  $a_{-ks}a_{-ks}^{\dagger}$ just changes the order of the elements but not the elements themselves.

That allows me to obtain the Hamiltonian; however I am still interested in a justification of the condition

$P^*(k)=P(-k)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

> $f(x)$ is real valued function $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\hat{f}^{\ast}(k)=\hat{f}(-k)$.

where the hat represents Fourier transform. Since $P$ is a real valued, this relation follows immediately.